# Managing report plugins in maven site

Tags: maven, maven-2, build, cobertura, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm using Maven 3 in a multi module project and configured site with following report plugins:
1. findbugs
2. cobertura
3. surefire report for tests

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${maven.site.version}</version>
              <configuration>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                      <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </reportPlugins>
              </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**If I use:**

> mvn site -DskipTests=true after mvn clean install

I dot not get proper reports after mvn site. Cobertura related test coverage report does not shows correct data i.e. all packages as 0% test coverage. It seems cobertura wants to run tests itself to determine coverage.

**But when I run**

> mvn site

This makes my all tests run twice once each for cobertura and surefire reports.

I want to run tests only once and generate the required reports. Please let me know the correct way to achieve this using above reportPlugins in maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cobertura and surefire report (for site generation) do two different things.  Hence you cannot avoid  running the tests twice - once for cobertura and one for site.

What you could look at is moving the cobertura run out of maven default life-cycle and run it separately as required.  This way, `mvn site` will only run surefire for site generation.